# Exception- java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 000000000"

Tags: java, double, numberformatexception

I have this return after a query in database, I dont know what exactly means.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 000000000"
```

Someone help me please. Thanks

Comment: How i can do this in number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

In your case you have a space in the number, you can trim it with `trim()`

> How i can do this in number?

Before attempting to parse the number you need to make sure it is formatted as a number.

e.g.

```
String s = " 00000000";
int n = Integer.parseInt(s.trim()); // remove leading/trailing spaces.
```

Comment: I'm not much active in [java], but is there really still no canonical duplicate for the particular exception like the one for NPE? This is worrying.

Answer (score 3):

This issue caused by number format exception. There is space in format input string: **" 000000000"**. Remove the space and try it again

Answer (score 2):

Look at this part of your error message:
`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 000000000"`

Parsing the number is failing because there is a space at the beginning of your number String.

Remove that space and it should work.